# str.replace() doesn't replace nor throw errors (python)

Tags: python, list, str-replace

So I scraped a list of heights from a website, and I am trying to find an average of these heights in ft and in. My problems is that the str.replace() is not working here and I am not sure why. (It doesn't give me any error messages) Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```py
> print(maleswimLIST)
> ['6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '6\'2"', '6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'8"', '5\'8"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'2"', '6\'0"', '6\'0"', '5\'11"', '6\'3"', '5\'10"', '5\'10"', '5\'5"', '6\'1"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'3"', '6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '6\'2"', '6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'8"', '5\'8"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'2"', '6\'0"', '6\'0"', '5\'11"', '6\'3"', '5\'10"', '5\'10"', '5\'5"', '6\'1"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'3"']
> for x in maleswimLIST:
    x.replace("\'",".")
    print(x)

> 6'5"
5'10"
5'9"
6'2"
6'5"
5'10"
5'8"
5'8"
5'10"
5'9"
5'7"
6'2"
6'0"
6'0"
5'11"
6'3"
5'10"
5'10"
5'5"
6'1"
5'9"
5'7"
6'3"
6'5"
5'10"
5'9"
6'2"
6'5"
5'10"
5'8"
5'8"
5'10"
5'9"
5'7"
6'2"
6'0"
6'0"
5'11"
6'3"
5'10"
5'10"
5'5"
6'1"
5'9"
5'7"
6'3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replace function you call on the string `x` doesn't change the value in place, you need to set it again:

```
result = []
for x in maleswimLIST:
    result.append(x.replace("'", ".")
print(result)
```

Or as a list comprehension which is more pythonic:

```
result = [x.replace("'", ".") for x in maleswimLIST]
```

BTW: there is no need to escape the apostrophe ' in your replace function.

Answer (score 1):

> My problems is that the str.replace() is not working here and I am not sure why. (It doesn't give me any error messages

`str.replace` doesn't work in-place, it returns a new string with the replacement applied. It also doesn't really care how many replacements it performs (whether 0 ot 1000), it will only raise errors if the input is nonsensical e.g. if you provide integers.

Here you would normally create a brand new list containing the transformed / converted values (using either a procedural `for` loop or a list comprehension) rather than try and update the values in-place.

Although note that your replacements here don't really make sense: imperial units are not decimal, there are not 10 inches to a foot but 12, so 5ft9 is 5.75 ft not 5.9ft.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't changed the value of `x`. `str.replace()` does not change the variable in place, you need to reassign the return value to x so that it takes effect when you call `print(x)` thereafter.

```
maleswimLIST = [x.replace("\'",".") for x in maleswimLIST]
```

Answer (score 0):

***Problem Explanation***

The [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method returns the new value, and the original value stays intact (strings are immutable)

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

***Code Fix***

Using list comprehension, iterating over the list, and collecting the replaced value:

```
male_swim_list =  ['6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '6\'2"', '6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'8"', '5\'8"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'2"', '6\'0"', '6\'0"', '5\'11"', '6\'3"', '5\'10"', '5\'10"', '5\'5"', '6\'1"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'3"', '6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '6\'2"', '6\'5"', '5\'10"', '5\'8"', '5\'8"', '5\'10"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'2"', '6\'0"', '6\'0"', '5\'11"', '6\'3"', '5\'10"', '5\'10"', '5\'5"', '6\'1"', '5\'9"', '5\'7"', '6\'3"']

male_swim_list = [x.replace("\'", ".") for x in male_swim_list]

print(male_swim_list)
```

Output:

```
['6.5"', '5.10"', '5.9"', '6.2"', '6.5"', '5.10"', '5.8"', '5.8"', '5.10"', '5.9"', '5.7"', '6.2"', '6.0"', '6.0"', '5.11"', '6.3"', '5.10"', '5.10"', '5.5"', '6.1"', '5.9"', '5.7"', '6.3"', '6.5"', '5.10"', '5.9"', '6.2"', '6.5"', '5.10"', '5.8"', '5.8"', '5.10"', '5.9"', '5.7"', '6.2"', '6.0"', '6.0"', '5.11"', '6.3"', '5.10"', '5.10"', '5.5"', '6.1"', '5.9"', '5.7"', '6.3"']
```

***Some Advice***

At least since [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it's a convention to name variables with lower case with underscores.
It doesn't change the behavior of the code, yet it is more readable for your future teammates.